# Login/logout HTTP authentication through XMLHttpRequest: IE sometimes pop up login window

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to have a custom login form to authenticate to a web server. The server is very simple (it is based on an embedded platform) so I can't use complex mechanism (php, asp, ssl, ...). For my needs, the basic HTTP authentication is good. Moreover I need logout feature.

I implemented login.html, /pages/protected.html and auth.js. 
The first is the index page with the login form. The submit button calls login() function in auth.js. 
The second is the protected page (all files under /pages folder are protected) that should be visible only for correct login. In this page there's a logout button that calls logout() function in auth.js.

This is the content of auth.js:

```
var loginURL = "/login.html";
var logoutURL = "/pages/logout.html";
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

function getHTTPObject() {
  var xmlhttp = false;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {                      // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return xmlhttp;
}

function login(strUrl) {
  var user = document.getElementById("txt_username").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("txt_password").value;
  var http = getHTTPObject();
  http.open("get", strUrl, false, user, pass);
  http.send("");
  if (http.status == 200) {
    document.location = strUrl;
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect username and/or password!");
  }
  return false;
}

function logout() {
  if (userAgent.indexOf("msie") != -1) {
    document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache", false);
  }
  var http = getHTTPObject();
  var logout_url = "/login.html";
  http.open("get", logout_url, false);
  http.send("");
  document.location = logout_url;
  return false;
}
```

The server is programmed to answer with 401 and WWW-Authenticate HTTP header if the request hasn't the Authorization header. It answers with 403 if the request contains Authoization header with bad credentials. In this way, I can avoid the browser login window with bad credentials.

With the last Firefox version this works very well and it works also for IE. But sometimes IE insists to popup its small dialog window with user/password text boxes, even if the credentials typed in the form are corrected.

I start the following loop:

1. type correct username and password
2. click login and protected page appears
3. click logout
4. go to step 1.

After n time (n could be 1, 5 or 10), after clicking on login button I receive the authentication form from IE.

As you know, after clearing credetials cache in IE (with ClearAuthenticationCache), firstly the browser sends the request without credentials (even if the XMLHttpRequest object has username and password parameters). Only if the web server answers with 401 code and WWW-Authenticate header the browser sends again the request with credentials.

I tried to implement the **same** pages with a lighttpd server on a normal PC. In this case, it seems IE doesn't have the popup problem. So IE doesn't like too much the answer of my embedded server (that is HTTP1.0). My server answers with the following HTTP headers:

- HTTP 1.0 (*200 for correct credetinals, 401 for no credentials, 403 for bad credetials*)
- Server
- WWW-Authenticate (*in case of no credetianls*)
- Connection: close
- Content-type

The answer from lighttpd (HTTP 1.1) has more headers:

- HTTP 1.1 and code
- WWW-Authenticate
- Content-type
- Content-length
- Date
- Server

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It seems the problem is with cache of IE. If I disable the cache at all (reload the page everytime) the problem with login popup window disappears. So I added the three famous headers for no caching with every HTTP response (Pragma: no-cache, Cache-control: no cache, Expires: -1) and the problem is absent even enabling the normal cache mechanism.